# html javascript connect to raw socket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a c# tcp server, I want to connect to the server via a html client page.

**The problem**: There is no simple way to create TCP sockets in Javascript on a browser side. Although solutions like Websockets allow to create something that resemble sockets, you can use them to connect only to servers that support Websockets. Not to any random servers that know nothing about HTTP.

so is there a solution to connect to my srver.

Answer (score 4):

No. There just isn't. The browser is a tightly locked down environment. The only socket connection that you can open from JavaScript is WebSocket. Since it's your server, adding WebSocket support shouldn't be too complicated, and there are WebSocket libraries available for C#.

Comment: what about this framework http://artemyankov.com/tcp-client-for-browsers/  
could it be a solution

Comment: Interesting. No idea how well this works, but a solution in principle. There's also https://github.com/kanaka/websockify. And my answer seems to be wrong concerning Chrome - see https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp

Comment: Added an upvote because you acknowledged you were wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone else will have an idea for you, but...

The best solution I can think of is for your server to support websockets.

The situation you described - along with connectivity issues for traffic passing through proxies and routers - is one of the reasons Websockets were introduced in the first place.

Bare in mind that Websockets can send and receive binary data. It's just that javascript make it more comfortable to write text based messages.

Also, many NAT routers, Proxies and firewalls will block raw TCP/IP communication while allowing Http communication to pass through. This is why you have a better chance at connection establishment and retention when implementing the Websocket protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late to this but, try creating a WebSocket "proxy".

Create a WebSocket server that connects to your raw socket server and passes on the data given to the WebSocket.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).